# Batch size, Epoch, and iteration in a many-to-one RNN

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

I am having trouble defining mainly the batch size when it comes to a many-to-one RNN.

I have been looking at the following article: https://medium.com/@erikhallstrm/hello-world-rnn-83cd7105b767

This is on a many-to-many RNN, but still the definition of the batch puzzles me.

**What is the batch size when it comes to a many-to-one RNN?**

This would probably answer my other two confusions on epoch and iteration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the example you link, a sequence is a vector of shape `(N,)`, since a sequence contains `N` binary numbers.

If instead of numbers, the items forming the sequence were vectors, each sequence would have shape `(N, item_size)`.

RNNs process several sequences at the same time, in parallel. This is what we call a batch. The number of sequences processed in parallel is the `batch_size`, and the shape of the input to the RNN will be `(batch_size, N)`.

In the many-to-one scenario, the batch size is the same. The only thing that changes is the output shape, because instead of producing an output of size `(batch_size, N)`, it will be just `(batch_size,)` (or `(batch_size, 1)`) since each sequence will be mapped to a single output.

To summarize, the batch size is the number of sequences processed in parallel, so there is no difference between the many-to-many and many-to-one cases.

Regarding your confusion with epoch/iteration, an **epoch** usually refers to iterating over the whole training dataset once, while **iteration** refers to processing a single batch to do one SGD step.